# How to Read mutliple images with FileReader

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Wanna Select Multiple Image from one input And Read It With File Reader ,  and if i leave it like this, it give me one picutre

```
   const [image , setImage] = useState('');
    const [imageSelected , setImageSelected] = useState(null);

    const onImageChange = event => {
       const reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = () => {
           if(reader.readyState === 2){
                setImageSelected(reader.result)
                console.log(reader.result)
           }
        }
        setImage(event.target.files[0]);
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0])
        console.log(image)
    }
```

HTML

```
 <label htmlFor="image" className = "col-span-3 ">
     {
       !imageSelected ? <PhotoCameraIcon fontSize="120" className ="border rounded p-2 h-24 text-8xl text-gray-600 cursor-pointer" /> : (

        <img src={imageSelected} alt="" className = "h-44" />
                                       )
                                            }
       <input hidden multiple onChange={onImageChange} type="file" name="image" id="image" />
 </label>
```

Comment: "I try foreach" — How? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: "it doesn't work" — [what does that mean?](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: i try to use foreach but it doesnt work

Comment: When people ask for more details, try providing more details instead of just repeating what you said already.

Answer (score 0):

```
import "./styles.css";


import React, {Component} from 'react';
    
export default class App extends Component {

    constructor (props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        images: null
      }
    }

    readFileContents = async (file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let fileReader = new FileReader();
            fileReader.onload = () => {
                resolve(fileReader.result);
            };
            fileReader.onerror = reject;
            fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
    }
    readAllFiles = async (AllFiles) => {
        const results = await Promise.all(AllFiles.map(async (file) => {
            const fileContents = await this.readFileContents(file);            
            return fileContents;
            //let a = URL.createObjectURL(fileContents);
            //return a;
        }));
        console.log(results, 'resutls');
        return results;
    }

    handleUpload = (e) => {
        let AllFiles = [];
        [...e.target.files].map(file => AllFiles.push(file));

        this.readAllFiles(AllFiles).then(result => {            
            let allFileContents = [];
            result.map(res =>{
                allFileContents.push(res);
            })
            this.setState({images: allFileContents});
        }).catch(err => {
            alert(err);
        });
    }

    render = () => {

        return (<div>
                <input type="file" multiple onChange={(e) => this.handleUpload(e)}/>
                {this.state.images && this.state.images.map((img, idx)=>{
                  return <img width={100} height={50} src={img} alt={idx} key={idx} />
                })
                
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```